# Web service works sometimes fine, sometimes not

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator

I was getting data from a web service from my Android code, and it was working fine in the emulator.

Then I connected my Android tablet to test the code, but the driver was not installed and Windows was not recognizing the device.

I then started the emulator again to continue my development, but this time my code was not working and saying that there is an error in the URI query of web service.

Why is this?
If any one knows, please help me out.

Comment: hard to tell. What kind of error are you getting? Probably a timeout, but it's anyone's guess so far.

Comment: i got the reason why itz not working.
there is not any problem in the code.
When i checked the internet using emulator's browser, the net was not working.
i restarted the emulator, checked the permission. nothing was wrong done by me.
I even restarted my pc.
problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

It was not the issue of disconnecting and reconnecting the android device that disturbs the emulator files. No!
My wireless adapter was actually not working fine, it was connecting and disconnecting with interval resulting in Internet packets transfer fail.

which loads the service and sometimes refuses.

~Help,when you think it's a help~